# Django on Windows 2003 Slow Initially

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, django

I have setup Django to run on a windows 2003 server following the steps on the [django wiki](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer). Everything works fine and there are no errors. Only one instance of Django is setup on the server at the moment. However whenever the first page is requested it takes about 10 seconds to load the page. After this every page loads instantly.

All my searches about speed issues with Django on windows refer to the local server, but not when using IIS and PyISAPIe.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does it do the same thing with the Django bundled server ?

Does you have any caching enabled ?
Perhaps it's trying to cache the page at the fist request but something block it...

Answer (score 0):

If you try a simple Python script running under PyISAPIe such as

```
from Http import *
def Request():
    Header("Content-type: text/html")
    Write("Hello, World!")
```

Does it take 10 seconds? This way you can try and eliminate (or narrow to) PyISAPIe / Python as the cause.